# Is a Grotesque font another name for a Gothic font?

Tags: typography, font-identification

Recently I have run across the class of a font and it was called Grotesque Sans.  When researched for what this was using `grotesque font definition` I was returned with:

> Gothic/Grotesque: Is frequently used as a synonym with sans serif. At
>   other times, it is used (along with "Neo-Grotesque", "Humanist",
>   "Lineal", and "Geometric") to describe a particular style or subset of
>   sans-serif typefaces.

So does this mean that a Gothic font is also called a Grotesque font or is there more to it?  The closest Q&A I was able to generate was [What makes a font a “gothic” font?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/what-makes-a-font-a-gothic-font)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I started writing this thinking that there were enough distinctions between Gothic and Grotesque typefaces to answer with confidence. However with their contemporary counterparts, **there are too many exceptions to discern any strong difference between the two**. Effectively, Gothic and Grotesque *seem to have become diluted* to mean nothing more than *sans-serif*, where heirs of the ‘Neo-’ prefix are concerned.

According to *The Geometry of Type*¹, **Grotesque Sans typefaces** appeared in the mid 19th century and were dubbed “grotesque” as they were so strange and novel at the time (“grotesk” for German-speakers).

They have similar properties to Transitional and Rational serif faces:

> - Regular proportions
> - Relatively static forms
> - Based on oval-shapes
> - “fairly closed apertures, with some strokes turning inward”

Older Grotesque faces like Bureau Grot have more irregular forms than newer grotesques, giving them an organic character. Neo-Grotesque Sans faces are more rationalized, modeled forms, and are more familiar to us. Examples include: Univers, Helvetica, Acumin & Akkurat.

[image]

**Gothic Sans typefaces** refer to:

> “some English and American variants of the Grotesque style”

Often the difference is *merely in the name alone*, however the following characteristics are usually notable:

> - Large x-height
> - Simple & static forms
> - Very low contrast
> - “Often a condensed width with an upright stance derived from flat-sided rounds”

[image]

---

¹ Coles, S. (2013), The Geometry of Type, 1st Ed., London: Thames & Hudson

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no difference. Gothic and Grotesque were used interchangeably for a wide variety of sans-serif fonts in the nineteenth century, without the names having separate meanings.